# About search functionality in Visual Studio Code 1.54

Tags: visual-studio-code

Moving into Visual Studio Code 1.54 from PHPStorm in Laravel project and reading manuals I did not find some features with search functionality:

- When I search in file and last item is found is it possible to notify about Last item and maybe move to first found element in the file?
- Has search functionality predefined dirs in scopes(or in some other way) like PHPStorm has

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the go to next item functionality to wrap beyond the end of the file, for example?  And how are you moving to the next item?

Comment: Say, if last element foud, then show some message in the background

Comment: There is no built-in functionality to do that.  You would have to find or make an extension.

Comment: Maybe somebody has made such extention ? Also pls pay attention I asked about scopes predefined dirs

Comment: `scopes predefined dirs` : can you explain a bit more or give a link where it is described

Comment: scopes ( predefined dirs ) - when I want not to search in all projects, but only in some subdirectories(say "app/models") - and select them without manually entering any time

Answer (score 1):

Control-Shift-F does a workspace-wide search, and it shows 3 text boxes:

1. The text to search for
2. Files to include. This is where you type in directory paths (make sure they start with ./), like `./mydir` or `./mydir/subdir/`
3. Files to exclude. Again, you can specify directory paths.

After you start the search you will see a pane fill with all the matches. PHPStorm/IDEA works similarly.

BTW, Control-Shift-H does a workspace-wide search-and-replace, and it works similarly.